# Построить гистограмму в R, зная распределение событий

Tags: r

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть данная таблица, как построить гистограмму, по этим данным? Знаю, что есть функция plot type="h", но она не похожа на ту, что дает функция hist (которая принимает 1 аргумент). Вопрос в том, можно ли не заполняя вектор 1000 элементами построить hist подобную гистограмму?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например, можно воспользоваться функцией `barplot()`:

```
$ barplot(c(1,2,8,26,65,120,180,201,170,120,64,28,10,3,1), \
    names.arg = paste(seq(143, 185, 3), seq(146, 188, 3), sep = "-"))
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]